# download a file with play web api (async)

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am trying to download a file using play api framework. Since all the data access layer has already been implemented with Futures I would like to get download to work with async action as well. However, the following piece of code does not work. And by not working I mean that the file sent to the client is not the same as the file on server.

```
  val sourcePath = "/tmp/sample.pdf"

  def downloadAsync = Action.async {
    Future.successful(Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File(sourcePath)))
  }
```

However, this piece works:

```
  def download = Action {
    Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File(sourcePath))
  }
```

Any suggestion on how I can get the async method to work?

Comment: Both `Action.apply` and `Action.async` are async! In first case you pass a "normal" value (not a Future) and in other case you pass a Future, see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAsync#actions-are-asynchronous-by-default). Since Play itself recommends the [second way](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaStream#serving-files)(and it will be async), that's the way to go.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to use `Action.async` here, since `Ok.sendFile` is non-blocking already. From [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync#Actions-are-asynchronous-by-default):

> Play actions are asynchronous by default. For instance, in the controller code below, the `{ Ok(...) }` part of the code is not the method body of the controller. It is an anonymous function that is being passed to the `Action` object’s `apply` method, which creates an object of type Action. Internally, the anonymous function that you wrote will be called and its result will be enclosed in a `Future`.
>
> ```
> def echo = Action { request =>
>   Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
> }
> ```
>
> **Note**: Both `Action.apply` and `Action.async` create Action objects that are handled internally in the same way. There is a single kind of Action, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one). The `.async` builder is just a facility to simplify creating actions based on APIs that return a Future, which makes it easier to write non-blocking code.

In other words, at this specific case, don't worry about wrapping your `Result` into a `Future` and just return `Ok.sendFile`.

---

Finally, both versions works as expected to me (the file was properly delivered). Maybe you are having another problem not related to how you have declared your actions.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried with a pdf file and it doesnt work. It works with sample text file.

Comment: And for the exact reason you mentioned I prefer to use async version as the data access layer methods all return Future results.

Comment: I've tried with an image and also a PDF now. Everything works like a charm.  Maybe you can add more information.

Comment: This is the actual implementation:  def download(reference: String)= SecuredAction.async { r =>
    logger.info(s"downloading document with reference: $reference")
    if (reference.isEmpty) Future.successful(BadRequest)
    else
      documentsService.getFiles(reference).map {
        case Some(files) => {
          Ok.sendFile(files.head)
        }
        case None => NotFound
      }
  }

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? I've tried with version 2.5.4 which is the latest release. About the "data access layer" returning `Future`s, I think that you should do the simplest thing, which, in this case, is just return `Ok.sendFile`.

Comment: Could the problem be on the client side? I'm using angular 2 on the client. the version that works has a direct link.

Comment: I'm using play 2.4.

Comment: I would try accessing both urls directly to figure it out if the server is responding as expected. Ideally, you can fire a request using `curl`.

Comment: Thanks will try that soon and report back.

Comment: The problem was in the client and had nothing to do with play implementation. Thanks.